# Android Facebook SDK Hash Key on Windows 7 64 bits

Tags: android, facebook, cygwin, facebook-android-sdk

**The problem:**

I can´t get a functional Hash Key. It works fine without FB app installed on the emulator but as @Jesse Chen says in the most famous answer about this subject it is not working properly.

**I've tried:**

- use openssl-0.9.8k_X64, openssl-0.9.8e_X6 and openssl-0.9.8e_WIN32.
- use openssl as a envoronment variable
  (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LrdUYk1wDlA)
- use openssl with it's respecting path.
- use debug.keystore with it's respecting path and without it.
- delete debug.keystore and regenerated it debugging the FB Samples.
- I 've tried the way it says on [FB tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/):

  ```
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  // Add code to print out the key hash
  try {
      PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
          "com.facebook.samples.hellofacebook", 
          PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
      for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
          MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
          md.update(signature.toByteArray());
          Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
       }
  } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {

  } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

  }
  ```

And I've got the same Hash Key than using CMD.

- I've installed Cygwing and tried to use it's terminal to get the hash but I couldn't make it require the password.. (So it's not working)

  ```
   EYYO@EYYO-PC /home
   $ wgetexe="/cygdrive/C/Program Files/java/jre7/bin"

   EYYO@EYYO-PC /home
   $ "$wgetexe"/keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore
   /cygdrive/C/Users/EYYO/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
  ```

Finally I share with you a short [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g5GoF4fEIPk&feature=youtu.be) of how emulator does not work. (not very fun)

If you have any question please ask me.

Answer (score 1):

After reading hundreds of sites and questions regarding this ussue its seems to me that FB is not offering a solution for this problem. Because of this I´ve decided that I´ll not include the SDK of this company on my Android App.

**Regards**